# how to write a value into application.properties in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I already saw [Write/Update properties file value in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334977/write-update-properties-file-value-in-spring)

In Spring boot

How to write a value into application.properties in spring boot?

application.properties:
ews.batch_type=
ews.batch_dat=
...other fields

I want:

application.properties:
ews.batch_type=**ALL**
ews.batch_dat=**20170222**
...other fields

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want to update the value during runtime?

Normally the `application.properties` is not a dynamic source for values but static. You run your application with these values and you don't update them. If you change them during runtime they are also not re-read into the spring components.

Comment: @ThomasPawlitzki : Yes , Sorry, My English is not good, I want to determine batch_type field , if no value , will set value:ALL. Also batch_dat will save executed time - 1 day.   20170221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you give some more information I guess you want to define default values. The `application.properties` is still static but you can do something in your Application to handle missing properties.

You can define default values

```
// Gets the Value of "ews.batch_type" or "ALL" if no property is defined
@Value("${ews.batch_type:ALL}")
private String batchType;

public static String getDate() {
    return "..."; // <- the date you want
}

@Value("#{ config['ews.batch_dat'] ?: T(yourClass).getDate() }")
private String date;
```

Comment: Is there any full example? Yes, I want to modify a property value and use it in the app.