# Writing file properties with spring boot

Tags: spring, properties

I've used the @PropertySource and @Value annotations for reading external file properties and it works great. But if I want to write the same @Value annotated properties out to an external file, can that be done? I've done some searching but can't seem to find a way of doing it. Is there native support for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the [DefaultPropertiesPersister](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/DefaultPropertiesPersister.html). An example is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334977/write-update-properties-file-value-in-spring/31335245#31335245).