# assign values to application.properties file Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a requirement where I get the DB URI, DB URL etc at runtime in JavaCode. This value needs to be available to application.properties for it to make a DB call.

I always used Spring boot to retrieve values assigned in application.properties file but not the other way
How do I achieve something similar db.uri = {comingFromJavaCode}

Comment: What gives these information at runtime?

Comment: Do you want to establish connection with database at the time of application startup?

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been answered in this stackoverflow thread. [Write/Update properties file value in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334977/write-update-properties-file-value-in-spring)

By the way, the application.properties file is only read by the spring boot application once during startup. Adding any new values to the file at runtime has no effect. The following stackoverflow thread explains how to reload the `application.properties` file during loadtime. [How can I reload properties file in Spring 4 using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations) . This article can also be of use: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot, you can add or update a property in the application.properties programmatically by using `System.setProperty(String key, String value)`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("key", "value");
        
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
        
    }
}
```

**Note**: Values defined using System.setProperty(String key, String value) takes precedence over the values in the application.properties files